# What is measure of a quadrilateral with an equalateral triangle within the shape?

Tags: geometry, angle, quadrilateral

[http://i.imgur.com/URCItTG.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/URCItTG.jpg)

[image]

BEC is an equilateral triangle and angle ABC is 130, what is the measure of angle ADC.

The answer I was given is 50 degrees, however I am curious as to steps required to get that specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angle A: $120^o$
Angle ABE: $130-60=70^o$  ($2x=60^o$ coz equilaterla triangle)

Angle DEB: $180-60=120^o$ (sum of angle in straight line is $180^o$)

Therefore Angle ADE: $360-70-120-120=50^o$ (sum of angles in a quad. is $360^o$)